# (Ruby) method to check if element already appeared

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a method that checks if we've seen an element more than once in a string.  This code is returning the string, but not the boolean---and I don't think it's even returning the right string!

Can anyone advise?

```
def repeating_letters?(str)
  # downcase the whole str
  # create a "seen letters" array
  # iterate through each char in array
  # if seen letters contains that character, return true
  down = str.downcase
  seen = []
  down.each_char do |index|
    if seen.include?(index)
      TRUE
    else
      seen << index
    end
  end
end

p repeating_letters?("aA")
```

Comment: Should `repeating_letters?("aA")` return `true` or `false`?

Comment: `str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)).any? { |c,h| h[c] += 1; h[c] == 2 }`

Comment: This question is a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate. To be fair, the accepted answers are inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this a lot easier:

```
def repeated_characters?(s)
  !! s =~ /(.)\1/
end
```

No arrays, no looping through strings, no counting, just a simple regular expression matching any character followed by that same character.

Or, if you don't care about adjacency, you can do this:

```
Set.new(s.chars).length == s.length

# or this:

s.each_char.uniq.length == s.length
```

Comment: Doesn't a regular expression with capture group and backreference imply arrays, looping and counting? ;-)

Comment: @Stefan If you want to worry about the implementation details of Oniguruma be my guest, but no…a backreference is looking at the previous match. It's a windowed scan operation.

Comment: If the repeated characters must be adjacent to each other (which I don't think is the case, in part from the title of the question), another way is `s.squeeze == s`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's nothing in the question that seems to indicate that only adjacent duplicates are considered. The second method should work, though.

Answer (score 2):

The issue in your code is that you waste your `true`, downcase by the way, you don't use it. And it's not so clear what you are trying to do. I'd have expected `seen` to be an hash in case.

```
def repeating_letters?(str)
  str.downcase.chars.group_by(&:itself).values.any? { |a| a.size > 1 }
end
```

`itself` is available from Ruby 2.3.0, otherwise

```
def repeating_letters?(str)
  str.downcase.chars.group_by { |c| c }.values.any? { |a| a.size > 1 }
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code has to process each char in the string before detecting a duplicate.

Comment: You could likely resolve that using `lazy`: http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/4/3/ruby-2-0-works-hard-so-you-can-be-lazy

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work, because [`String#each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-each_char) returns the receiver, i.e. the string. You have to use an explicit `return` instead: (I've fixed some minor issues, too)

```
def repeating_letters?(str)
  seen = []
  str.downcase.each_char do |char|
    if seen.include?(char)
      return true           # <- you need a `return` here
    else
      seen << char
    end
  end
  return false              # <- last statement, so `return` is optional
end
```

Or you could use [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) which returns `true` if the block ever returns `true` (and `false` otherwise):

```
def repeating_letters?(str)
  seen = []
  str.downcase.each_char.any? do |char|
    if seen.include?(char)
      true
    else
      seen << char
      false
    end
  end
end
```

This can be shorted by using a hash to *count* the characters:

```
def repeating_letters?(str)
  seen = Hash.new(0)
  str.downcase.each_char.any? { |char| (seen[char] += 1) == 2 }
end
```

Within the block, the hash's value for `char` is incremented by one and compared to `2`, which indicates whether the char was seen before.

I'd also move `downcase` from the method to the caller to make the code a little more versatile:

```
def repeating_letters?(str)
  seen = Hash.new(0)
  str.each_char.any? { |char| (seen[char] += 1) == 2 }
end

repeating_letters?('aA'.downcase)
```

Comment: Your last method is short, readable and should return as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def check(str)
  repeated = false
  str.downcase.split.uniq.each { |i| repeated = true and break if str.count(i) > 1 }
  repeated
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def repeating?(str)
  str.downcase!
  seen = {}
  str.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
    if index !=0 && str[0..(index-1)].include?(char)
      seen[char] = seen[char].nil? ? 2 : seen[char]+=1
    end
  end
  seen
end
```

output

```
> p repeating?("peEterr")
{"e"=>3, "a"=>2}
```

Comment: This is *really* slow on long strings, for what it's worth. If you wanted to get the counts for each character you'd be better off using [count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-count).